# Restrict choice field visibility per sharepoint group

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a choice field with 3 choices: Approved, Rejected, Resubmit

I want one  SharePoint group to see Approved and Rejected and another SharePoint group to see only resubmit option.

Comment: We may change the choice field to a lookup field. Then lookup to a list with 3 records Approved,Rejected,Resubmit. Then change item level permission on that list. [Ref](https://www.accelebrate.com/library/sharepoint-lookup-column)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SP 2013 (or later) and you need this restriction only on the Web UI, the simplest solution I can imagine is to create a custom rendering template for your field via JSLink.

JSLink and display templates are a quite huge topic, but you find a very good overview of them [here](http://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1.html).

Comment: How do you render JSLink differently according to SharePoint group?